# Error Trying to migrate from icefaces to primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, jsf-1.2, icefaces

I´m working on a migration of a project developed with Spring 3, JSF 1.2 and Icefaces 1.x to Spring 3, JSF 2-2 and PrimeFaces 6-2. (Yeah, it´s a huge change).
 I've follow Balus guide in [Migrating JSF1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but didn't find any guide to migrate Ice to Prime.
 I've delete every old file/folder/jar of Ice and replace everty tag in .xhtml's pages. But I guess I'm loosing some reference somewhere. Got this error now:

```
ADVERTENCIA: JSF 2.0 libraries detected. This version of ICEfaces is not supported on JSF 2.0. JSF 1.1 or 1.2 are required.
31-may-2018 11:20:47 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
GRAVE: Critical error during deployment:
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Must have a Constructor that takes in a ComponentConfig
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Must have a Constructor that takes in a ComponentConfig
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.<init>(AbstractTagLibrary.java:330)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.addComponent(AbstractTagLibrary.java:558)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagLibraryImpl.putComponent(TagLibraryImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processComponent(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:588)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:368)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:222)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:485)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:637)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:164)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.icesoft.faces.component.facelets.IceComponentHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.<init>(AbstractTagLibrary.java:328)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.addComponent(AbstractTagLibrary.java:558)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagLibraryImpl.putComponent(TagLibraryImpl.java:115)
... 43 more
31-may-2018 11:20:47 javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
GRAVE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
31-may-2018 11:20:47 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
GRAVE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle
java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key severe.no_factory_backup_failed
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:374)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:334)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1133)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:319)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:482)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextDestroyedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.destroy(WebAppServletContext.java:3228)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletContextManager.destroyContext(ServletContextManager.java:248)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.unloadWebApp(HttpServer.java:461)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.destroyContexts(WebAppModule.java:1536)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.deactivate(WebAppModule.java:509)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:389)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:223)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.deactivate(ModuleStateDriver.java:141)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.deactivate(ScopedModuleDriver.java:207)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.deactivate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:261)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$2.previous(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:548)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:223)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.deactivate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.deactivate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:185)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.previous(BaseDeployment.java:643)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:223)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:63)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:164)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
31-may-2018 11:20:47 com.icesoft.faces.util.event.servlet.ContextEventRepeater contextDestroyed
```

This is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- Comentar el de arriba y descomentar este para jdeveloper>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>public_html/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping-->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        60
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Servlets de ICEFaces -->
<!--<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
           com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>-->
<!-- Mapeo de servlets -->
<!--<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!--<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>-->
<!-- Facelets -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Faces Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<!--<listener>
    <listener-class>com.icesoft.faces.util.event.servlet.ContextEventRepeater</listener-class>
</listener>-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!--    PARA SUBIR ARCHIVO-->
<!--<context-param>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.uploadDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>upload</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
    <param-value>15728640</param-value>-->
    <!-- MAX FILE SIZE -->
<!--</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.component.inputfile.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 3 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadHtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>-->
```

This is my faces-config

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->
<faces-config version="2.2" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
<application>  
    <message-bundle>cr.ac.ucr.framework.vista.util.ErroresBundle</message-bundle>
    <locale-config>  
        <default-locale>es</default-locale> 
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>  
    </locale-config>     
    <!--<view-handler>com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler</view-handler> -->
    <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>principal</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/presentacion/principal.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/paginas/principal.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Any ideas of what am I missing?

Comment: There still must be an icefaces jar somewhere in your deployed application OR in the server lib folder

Comment: Thanks Kuke.. Didn't look in server lib folder... One problem solved.. This migration is really hard